# Assign A Process Id C#

Tags: c#

I am sending messages to a listener windows service. Within the message is a process id. I want to use the process id to attach it to my windows service in order to access a folder on the server.

I cannot see how to set a process id only get one

```
int nProcessID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not assign an ID to a process, it is only set by the operating system. You can however search for one by name:

```
int yourProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName( "YourListener.exe" )[0].Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing a bit the answer of [@BillyDvd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33483344/7586301), I suggest you getting the name of your process instead of hardcoding it, this way, you can change it in your project structure safely:

```
var name = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName; // always fix, like "myapp.rms"
var myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(name)[0].Id; // variable, given new by Windows OS on every start of your app: 44580, 36960, 38184, ...
```